# Would armor that you're wearing and weapons be counted in your carry weight?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

I've heard people who run games where they don't count armor that you wear in your carry weight and people who do.  I'm wondering what the RAW would state - does it count?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**It Counts**

From the [SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity):

> Encumbrance by Weight: If you want to determine whether your
>   character's gear is heavy enough to slow him down more than his armor
>   already does, total the weight of all the character's items, *including
>   armor, weapons, and gear*.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they count.

I think this question and many of your other questions can be answered by the general rule of RPG systems.

**If the game doesn't *say* there's an exception, there's not an exception.** The way the game works is to lay out general rules, and then state explicit exceptions. If the exception isn't stated, then the general rule applies.